# Global sections of twisting ideal sheaf of a smooth closed point on a projective space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X = \mathbb{P}^n_k$ be a projective space over an algebraically closed field $k$ and $x$ be a closed point.

Given an integer $m$ and a positive integer $r$.

What are the global sections of $\mathcal{O}_X(m) \otimes \mathcal{I}_x^r$ where $\mathcal{I}_x$ is the ideal sheaf of $x$ ?

Or what is the dimension of $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X(m) \otimes \mathcal{I}_x^r)$ ?

Comment: Did you try to compute this for yourself?

Comment: I computed for n = 2, m = 1, r = 3 and x = [1,0,0].
What I get is h^0(X,O(1) \otimes I^3) = 0
and h^0(X,O(1)) = 3 , h^0(X,O(1) \otimes O_X/I^3) = 3.
From the exact sequence 0 \to O(1) \otimes O_X/I^3 \to O(1) \to O(1)\otimes I^3 \to 0, we have a long exact sequence and get 
H^0(X,O(1)) \to H^0(X,O(1) \otimes I^3) is surjective.
But from what I recently read, it is wrong.
So I don't know where I go wrong.

Comment: You have incorrectly computed `$h^0(\mathbb{P}^2,\mathcal{O}(1)/\mathcal{I}_x^3\mathcal{O}(1))$`.  The dimension should be $6$, not $3$.

Comment: The cohomology group corresponds to the vector space of homogeneous polynomials in $x_0,\ldots,x_n$ vanishing at $p$ with multiplicitly $r$. That is, the Taylor expansion of $f$ near $p$ has the form $f=f_r+\ldots+f_m$ where $\deg f_j=j$. Using this description you can show that

$
\dim \Gamma(\mathbb P^n,I_x^r(m))=\max\left(0,{m+n \choose n}-{r+n-1 \choose n}\right)
$ (I might have the binomial coefficients wrong..)

Comment: Thanks. Jason Starr and J.C. Ottem
I found where I misunderstood.